# Как в Discord боте принимать все сообщения, кроме вызова команды?

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно, чтобы бот принимал все сообщения, кроме команд от пользователей. На данный момент он пропускает только свои же сообщения.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

В последней строке проверяется команда это или нет, но дело в том, что этот метод не выдаёт ничего на ответ (None). Что можно сделать в таком случае?